# Do the Early Bird or Night Owl ordinances effect Club LOL?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In the morning I try to go to Club LOL, but it says it's 12 PM to 2 AM. Do the Night Owl or Early Bird ordinances effect Club LOL's time slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They affect the normal hours but not KK Slider's performances.